# How can I achieve this website project deployment strategy?

Tags: deployment

I have a small team working on web site project using Visual Studio 2010 and with Team Foundation server 2012.

In order to have proper control on deployment, I would like to implement my dream deployment strategy as shown in the [figure](https://www.dropbox.com/sc/foy5fh7pntreiha/AAB4L4hhbpjcm1zHi6VBLSa6a) ( https://www.dropbox.com/sc/foy5fh7pntreiha/AAB4L4hhbpjcm1zHi6VBLSa6a  )

There is no problem for my team to perform the check in/out between their development pc with the TFS server. But I have problem to deploy code from TFS server to targeted web server.

I read many articles talking about build deploy, but for me I don't think I need to do build because mine is not a web application and we basically have all the codes in the targeted web server. We don't need to build the project into dll and then only upload to web server.

I tried using "copy website" feature in Visual Studio 2010, but on the copy website panel, it is always local programmer pc code at the left hand side and the targeted web server on the right hand side.

I wanted this deployment flow because I think this is the safest flow so that no one will accidentally upload the wrong version of code into the web server. Everyone would have no choice but to check in their code(s) into the TFS server before he/she can upload into the web server.

Please kindly help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Dont do that.

Instead use Stage / Production server, Stage and Master git branches,

Tell them to exclusively work out of stage, you control the merge to master,

use deployhq or similar service to hook into git(github) and trigger automatic deployments.

Much better than VS, much safer. Should a deploy not work due to file error, DHQ will prevent the entire deployment and revert to old state.

Comment: Nick, thanks for your comment. FYI, this website of mine is in a company intranet and we are not allowed to use tools such as GIT. Any other method with the current TFS and web server that I have access to in order to achieve what I wanted?

Comment: I know of nothing for the intranet. Any tool will be downloaded from somewhere, and I would trust it less than GIT. Only thing i could think of is to build your own internal webhook / provisioning platform with GIT (not github); if you are able to download git but keep the code within the lan.